# Find the absolute size of a class and all its contents

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, sizeof, stack-memory

I have a class:

```
class DelayContainer
{
public:
    explicit DelayContainer(std::vector<int> intervals, std::shared_ptr<IDelayCalculator> calc);
    void insertMeassurements(std::vector<qos::models::Meassurement> & ms);
    void printToCOUT();
    void clearCurrentEntry();
    float getAverage(int interval);
    float getFractile(int interval);
    float getMinDelay(int interval);
    float getMaxDelay(int interval);
    jitterContainer& getJitterContainer(int interval);
    unsigned short getNextMinute();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::map<float, std::map<unsigned short, int>>> container_;

    short getMinuteBefore(int minutesBack) const;
    unsigned short curMinute_ = 0;
    float getDelayBin(float delay) const;
    float daydelay = 0;
    float dayCount = 0;
    std::map<int, CalcValues> calcs_;
    shared_ptr<IDelayCalculator> delayCalc_;
};
```

This class can end up containing quite a bit of data. 
The problem seems to be, that the data is mainly found within `container_` which is a pointer.

That means when I make a sizeof(), I get a result of 48 bytes. Which doesn't seem right.

Is there any way that I can get the absolute size of the class, with all its contents and pointers data? 
I'm not interested in the size of the datatypes itself, but the actual size, which depends on the number of inputs in the maps and so on.

Hope anyone can help.

Best regards

Comment: You can provide a member function reporting total memory consumption as you see it. Notice that `sizeof` gives a size at compile-time, while getting total memory consumption can only be possible at runtime.

Comment: How would such a memberfunction look like?

Comment: Well, just a regular member function that sums up total memory consumption of each class field. To keep track of total memory consumption of standard container, such as map, you'll probably need to supply your own allocator.

Comment: Without knowing the internal structure of say `std::map` you would have to approximate it: size of each data type you know it must hold plus an unknown overhead times the number of elements it currently holds.